# UV Map overlap / odd result

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I'm making simple extruded letters for a quick sign concept. When I UV unwrap the face of any of my letters it has a strange result. Faces seem to converge on one single point even though my model is completely fine (to the best of my knowledge).

Anyone know if this is a bug or an error on my part?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I updated my Blender from 2.8 to 2.81a. That fixed my problem, therefore it must have been a bug.

Comment: Since it appears to be a fixed bug (IMO no one should be using 2.80) have voted to close as Off topic: re  a bug in blender (With no need to file a bug report)

Answer (score 0):

If encountering this problem again, it could be helped by triangulating the face. (Ctrl + T)
The face you are unwrapping is a so called N-Gon, which is a face with more than 4 corners/vertices. They sometimes give some calculation issues. By making everything triangles you force blender to calculate correctly.